# "Error; triggering view is invalid" when trying to make a view with instead of insert trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna make a view within the schema "HRM_ACCESS". The view has to be a selection of al employees sorted by departmentname. After that I made a instead of trigger on the view.

The problem is that i get the following output ;
*Warning: View created with compilation errors.
Trigger TRIGGER_EMPLOYEES compiled
Errors: check compiler log
Trigger "HRM_ACCESS"."TRIGGER_EMPLOYEES" altered.*

the compilers says: "error: triggering view is invalid"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "HRM_ACCESS"."EMP_DEP" ("FIRST_NAME", "LASTNAME", "DEPARTMENTNAME", "DEPARTMENT_ID") AS 
  select first_name , lastname , departmentname, department_id
-- Uit de tabellen:
  from hrm_repo.employees emp, hrm_repo.departments dep
-- Koppeling van department_id uit beide tabellen
  where emp.department_id = dep.department_id
-- Sorteren op departmentname
  order by departmentname;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "HRM_ACCESS"."TRIGGER_EMPLOYEES" 
/*vervanger door hetvolgende*/
  instead of insert or delete or update
  on emp_dep
/*Voor elke rij wordt hetvolgende uitgevoerd.*/
  for each row
begin
 if inserting then
/*nieuwe waarden geinjecteerd in de tabel*/
    insert into hrm_repo.employees (first_name, department_id)
    values (:new.first_name, :new.department_id);

/*als er wordt gedeletet dan wordt dit volgende uitgevoerd. */
else if deleting then
    delete from hrm_repo.employees
    where department_id = :old.department_id
    and first_name = :old.first_name;

 /*als update statement wordt uitgevoerd wordt dit gedaan:*/
else if updating then
    update hrm_repo.employees
    set first_name = :new.first_name,
    department_id = :new.department_id
    where first_name = :old.first_name
    and department_id = :old.department_id;

    end if;
    end if;
    end if;
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "HRM_ACCESS"."TRIGGER_EMPLOYEES" ENABLE;
```

Can somebody help me explain why i get this error?
:)

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  There is also no reason to put column names in double quotes.  However, those are not related to your particular error.

Comment: This looks like oracle rather than mysql - are you working with oracle or trying to convert oracle to mysql?